# Which is the correct form? "solutions *for*/*to* exercises *in*/*from* [name of the book]"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am writing solutions manuals for exercises in Mathematics books, and I would like to know how to properly phrase the titles.

Which is the correct form? "solutions *for*/*to* exercises *in*/*from* [name of the book]"?

Thanks in advance and kind regards from Brazil.

Comment: Use "to" and "in" respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is this because of any grammar rules or just common usage?

Comment: It's just common usage. By the way, if your solutions answer *all* the exercises in the book in question, then use the definite article: "Solutions to the exercises in [book]"

Comment: Thanks a lot. Closely related: when we talk about equations, it is also solutions *to* the given equation?

Comment: Yes, same thing.